# How does URL routing work when using headless CMS with nextjs or reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, headless

So I've been looking into headless CMS's and the only question I have about it is how routing is handled.

I want content editors to be able to create any page they want in the CMS and that be reflected in the head. A lot of the examples I've looked at are just doing blogs and they create a blog folder with [slug].js under the /pages or /app in the directory and that's it. But my issue is that the content editors need to create any page at any time with the components that are available in the head.

From my perspective I think I'm wondering whether the head resolves routes with what it gets from the API and is more like a component library that gets put together at runtime.

For example, if a content editor wants to create the page at mysite.com/newpage/child how does the head resolve this without a definite page declaration of its own under /pages or /app? And same thing for other examples like creating a new page at mysite.com/otherpage. etc.

Am I completely wrong? Am I asking a silly question?